# Setting up a ASP.NET MVC3 web application using SQL and XML sources

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I just started a tutorial for `MVC3 applicaton` on C# and I set up the project. The tutorial does not have any content on how I can add the two sources to my project:

1. `SQL`: the Orders and Customers tables from the classical `SQL Northwind` database, given as a standalone file, Northwnd.mdf,
2. `XML`: the `XOrders.xml` and `XCustomers.xml` files, which are XML mappings of the above Orders and Customers tables.

Now my question is that how can I add these tables to my project (similar to mvc2)? If someone has a link for any tutorial or even know how to do it can you please share it.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23654

Download the Files above and extract the files as stated [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143221%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  You can use [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3743) as your database engine.

Whats the link to the tutorial you are using?

Comment: I have SQL Server 2008 R2. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3 link to tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I managed to sort this out on my own and here is how:

I already have the `Northwnd.mdf` file so I used
 the `Server Explorer` in Visual Studio 2010 and 
`Right clicked` and then 
`add connection` and then 
`SQL Server Database File` and then 
`Browse` the location of the file. This adds the source for .mdf.

Will edit answer once I find how to do the XML source too.